# Server side ASP in an HTA

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, hta

I am very new to HTAs, but quite familiar with websites, javascript, ASP etc.  I have an HTA which needs to read some configuration files on the disk to get its display data etc. I have written the vbscript to do this and can execute it within a  tag in the HTA.  This is fine and works nicely.

However, given my javascript and, more recently, jQuery background, I am a lot more comfortable with DOM manipulation etc in jQuery that I am in VBScript.  I thought I would be clever and use jQuery.ajax to get my config files processed and return JSON data to the main page.  However, when I get the returned data from the .get call, its just the .asp code rather than the data it is supposed to output.  It looks very much like the ASP tags are not being recognised, hence the code is not running.

I've kind if confirmed this by putting a 'response.Write' statement inside '<%..%>' tags in the main code and observed nothing is output.

So, am I right in thinking I can't execute server side ASP from an HTA?

Thanks,
Al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right ASP is server-side technology host by IIS.  On the client side Internet Explorer is used to host a HTA.  IE does not support `<% %>` nor any of the ASP objects like `Response`.  The equivalent to `Response.Write` in a HTA is `document.write`.

Comment: Thanks Anthony - make sense now.  Had forgotten that the ASP side was IIS rather than IE.